# Unexpected items from a Dictionary of Dictionaries

Tags: vba, dictionary, collections

I've been working with VBA for the last couples of years, but I've never seen this before. Since there are 4 diferent steps, I'll try to ilustrate each one:

In the **first step** I'll validate if the integer variable exist in the dictionary object:
[image: Step1]

As you can see there is no variable in the first dictionary nor in the second nor in the Collection

**Step 2:** The integer variable doesn't exist so lets go with else:
[image: Step2]

**Step 3:**
The double variable (PAc_Cie) has been added to the Collection and this has been added to the dictionary DTM0, so in the dictionary we have ONE ITEM as you can see:
[image: Step3]

**Step 4**

Finally we've added the first dictionary to the second one called DSEÑa nd here its the problem:

Why we have 3 items in place of just one item?

[image: Step4]

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question is very hard to answer in the shape it is now.

Comment: @Sam, Thanks Sam. I´ll try it

Comment: A [mcve] which provides your code would be much more useful than screenshots of what happens when you run code which we are not able to (easily) run ourselves.

Comment: @JohnColeman, Thanks a lot John, but I try to illustrate with the variables results from the local window, and the only way I know is that

Comment: The problem is that we can't *experiment* with your code ourselves. I have no desire to manually type code from a screenshot, especially when I don't know how that code was called. If code is relevant to your question, then put it in the question itself, enough for it to be a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks John, I'll do this way. Thanks again for your comment and help

Comment: If by "this way" you mean the way that you are currently doing, you are unlikely to get any answer. Based on your screenshot, I am unable to replicate your problem, which likely involves code that you have neglected to show. For example -- your dictionary `DSEN` was never initialized in the code that you show, but in other parts of the screen shot, it *has* apparently been initialized. Unless you make it possible for others to reproduce the problem, it is unlikely that you will receive the help that you seek.

Comment: @JohnColeman. You were right and also I found the problem. As you said, as I not showed the rest of the code you couldn't see where was the problem. My first goal was show the problem in the _Intermediate Window_, and the only way I know is that. But anyway as the code is in a class, the problem appeared adding items to the dictionary from a property